# Magento 2 API with multipart form data

Tags: magento2

I am working on custom API development where i want to create multipart form post method for image upload.

Comment: Form data is not supported in magento 2 api. You can upload image by sending base64 encoded image data through json.

Comment: But as per standard multipart form images upload it better the base64 encoded image upload.

Comment: But magento only perse the json data for rest api.

Comment: you can check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/marketplace/eqp/files.html, there may be some way.

Comment: Have you get any solution for submit multi part form data ?